# How to access text of JTextArea of one class (or .java file) in Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have 2 java files. one is `inside.java` and other one is `editor.java`(which is an `applet`).
I have one `JTextArea` in `inside.java` file. When a user clicks "edit" button, it should run an `applet` and all the text from `JTextArea` of `inside.java` should be copied in `JTextArea` of `applet`.

How should I do that?

currently I am using `desktop.open()` to invoke `editor.jnlp` file. Is there any other way to run `applet` and access variable?

inside.java-->

```
private void editActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    File file= new File("C://Users//user//Documents//NetBeansProjects//blogspot//dist//editor.jnlp");
    try{
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ex:" + e.toString());
    };
}
```

Comment: *"I have 2 java files. one is `inside.java` and other one is `editor.java` (which is an applet)."*  Why is it an applet?  That will probably need to change for this to be practical.

Answer (score 0):

save the content of your JTextArea in a static variable like

```
public class Inside{

public static String TEXT_CONTENT = null;

//then when you saves the content:

TEXT_CONTENT = txtS.getText();
}

//then when you try to use it in another class:
String contentSaved = Inside.TEXT_CONTENT;
```

Hope it fits your requirements. Best regards. (I avoid some code that I am sure you already know).

Comment: Thank you. Well Actually it should work but when I did the same `contentSaved` had a null value associated with it. Is it because `editor.java` applet has a `run` method on another thread?

Comment: have you tried setting a default value like TEXT_CONTENT = "hello", to see if it is changing? I don't think that running in different threads should be a problem.

Comment: Yes. I did. in `inside.java` `Text_content` prints out text of JTextarea, while in `editor.java` it shows null. If possible could you please cast a light on invoking `applet` from another java program? I think I'm doing it wrong then.

Comment: Another Java app. invoked using the desktop will not just be in another thread, but another instance of the JVM.  No declaration of static or typical 'share this data throughout the VM' functionality will be able to transmit data between the two VM instances.